# 3D Engines for development on any mobile platform

Tags: android, iphone, windows-mobile, intel, amd-processor

I am planning to develop a game for all of the mobile platform and have pretty much zeroed down on the concepts of the game. but the only issue I'm facing as of now is that I have no idea what would be the best libraries + 3d Engine to us to achieve the best results on the hardware on some of the upcoming mobiles. I'm talking about the iPhone 3GS, the new WinMo and Android devices with the famed Snapdragon, other processors from Samsung, ARM, Qualcomm and even Intel and AMD.
as of now i plan to use the ogre libraries for now, but then what will offer portability?? This is much more of a design question rather than just coding. Any help is appreciated, others who wish to collaborate are very much welcome too. just drop me a mail.

Comment: @iH8 (via [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6255327)): Please don't just remove that tag, as it is needed.  Consider replacing it with [[tag:amd-processor]], but don't just delete it.  In this case I've done it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Window Mobile, but (right now) there is a barrier to compatibility between Android and the iPhone: managed vs. native code. Android highly encourages you to write in Java, whereas the iPhone requires Objective-C or C++ (or C). Though Android does have  a native development kit, they don't currently expose many libraries. They will add more APIs over time, but the Android devs will continue to encourage Java development, since Dalvik bytecode will run on any new device.

This is just my opinion, but I would focus on just one platform at the start. Pick your primary platform, write your core game code in portable C++ if you can, and keep the platform-specific parts separate from your core game code. Your goal is to get your game published. Once you have some money coming in, then start focusing on your second platform's port.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use OpenGL ES and STL. Both Android and iOS platforms become more compatible with OpenGL and STL library, and it looks like every other mobile platform would follow this course (except, perhaps, Windows Phone 7.)